# StackOverFlow in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've two recyclerview in one activity and then I add setOnScrollListener on both of them. Then I got a stackoverflow error but if I remove the other listener it's working fine. But I need a listener on both of them. Help !!

Comment: Do not use 2 in a single Activity.

Comment: But I have too. Anyways I already know the reason.

Comment: What? This question is very unclear.